# Custom Document Property with link to content not updated when reading in form

Tags: excel, vba

In order to map title block metadata I have added rangenames and custom document properties with same name. Rangenames and cust doc prop are linked to content. I have created an form which reads the cust doc properties so that a user can adjust this if need be. When closing the form it saves back the new value into the range name and consequently into the cust doc prop and form is closed. When again showing the form, it still reads the old value from the cust doc prop. While under file/prop the revised value is shown.

Seems a bug to me.

> ## Reading the cust doc prop before show form
>
> ```
> For Each p In ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties
> On Error GoTo Errorhandler
> 'Match the property with the position in the array, i=0 if not found
> i = IndexTCProp(p.Name)
> If p.Name = "TC_Project_Name" Then Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name, i,  'p.Name, p.Value
>  'fill the form with the found TC Prop and it's value.
>   If i > 0 Then
>     ipos = ipos + 1
>     frm_DocProp.Controls.Item("label_" & ipos).Caption = ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(aTC_Prop(ipos, 1)).Name
>     frm_DocProp.Controls.Item("text_" & ipos).Value = ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(aTC_Prop(ipos, 1)).Value
>     frm_DocProp.Controls.Item("text_" & ipos).Enabled = True  'Default editable
>   End If
> Next
> ```
>
> ## In form the changed value is written to the cell and linked cust doc prop.
>
> ```
> Private Sub cb_OK_Click()
> Dim x As Integer
> Dim p As DocumentProperty
> ' Write changes into cust doc prop
> For x = LBound(aTC_Prop) To UBound(aTC_Prop)
>    On Error Resume Next
>    Range(aTC_Prop(x, 1)) = frm_DocProp.Controls.Item("text_" & x).Value
> Next
> Unload Me
> End Sub
> ```

Loading the form and reading the changed cust doc prop again still shows the old values. Values shown under File/Properties/Custom show the changed value.
Is this a bug or do I need to refresh something ?

Comment: I don't see where you write the new value back to `CustomDocumentProperties`. I'm missing a line beginning with some `ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(aTC_Prop(ipos, 1)).Value = `. Additionally I'd remove `On Error Resume Next` if something is wrong, at least for the time of debugging.

Comment: Writing the value back to the 'linkedtocontent' range pushes the value into the custom document property. This can be seen if one goes to file/properties/custom. So I was under the impression that if I call my form again these values would be loaded. This does not seem the case.

Comment: In meanwhile I solved the issue by having the form load the values from the (linkedtocontent) named ranges instead of customdocprop.